# mvn を Stub Project (No Pom) で強制実行するには？

Tags: maven

mvn を pom が存在しない場所で実行すると、 Stub Project (No Pom) で、実行が始まります。

`mvn deploy:deploy-file` など、 pom が存在していなくても実行したくなるような plugin は mvn にいくつか存在していると思っています。

むしろ、 pom がない場所で実行していてうまくいっていた plugin が、 pom があるフォルダでたまたま実行してしまったがために、おかしな挙動をしてしまうのを(念のため)防ぎたい、と考えました。特に、マルチモジュールのプロジェクトなどで、 cd を繰り返しながら操作していると、今自分がどこにいるかを意識せずに、 pom を読まないような、 mvn 実行をしたくなる場合があります。

pom.xml が存在するフォルダ下でも、それを読まず、 Stub Project (No Pom) にて mvn を動作させたいのですが、これを実現する方法はありますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

いくつか調べてみましたが、多分そんなものは mvn の設計思想上、存在しなさそうで、できるとしたら dummy の pom を用意して実行するラッパを書く、ぐらいなのかなと思ってます。

```
#!/bin/sh

cat <<'EOF' > dummy_pom.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>dummy</groupId>
  <artifactId>dummy</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>dummy</name>
</project>
EOF

mvn -f dummy_pom.xml "$@"
```